# Need help to locate the files along with size

Tags: powershell, filesystems

I wrote a script in powershell to locate the files in share drives which takes the names of files from a .txt file. The script is as below.

```
$Files= Get-Content lock.txt
foreach ($File in $Files) {
    get-childitem -path Z:\lonmgb003_2 -Name $File -Recurse
}
```

Could someone help me with identifying size of file along with path. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks Mathias and Vivek. Both scripts did work but taking long time to execute. I have triggered the script for 28 entries last night and the script is still running which is more than 12 hours. Is there a way to pace up the script.

Answer (score 1):

The `-Name` parameter is a switch - it doesn't take an argument - and it causes `Get-ChildItem` to output just the file name and nothing else. The `$File` argument is instead being bound to the `-Filter` parameter.

Remove the `-Name` parameter and then use the `Select-Object` cmdlet to select just the path and size.

Since you have all the file names in an array already, you might as well use the `-Include` parameter to retrieve them all at once:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Z:\lonmgb003_2 -Include $Files -Recurse |Select FullName,Length
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need the `Length` and `FullName` properties of the files. You can do something like this.

```
$array= @() 
$Files= Get-Content lock.txt
foreach ($File in $Files)
{
        get-childitem -path Z:\lonmgb003_2 -Recurse | ?{$_.Name -like $File}
        $obj = New-Object PSObject  
        $Size = [Math]::Round((Get-ChildItem -Recurse $_.FullName | Measure-Object Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Sum / 1MB, 2) 
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Path" $_.FullName 
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SizeinMB" $Size 
        $array +=$obj 
 } 

$array | select Path, SizeinMB
```

What i have done is create a custom PS object that will store the `FullName(precisely path)` and `Size` of all the files. The use of `-Name` property doesn't help as it would just return you file name as a `string` and not the name as file (whose property you can use). Hence, a `where-Object` to match the file names in the text file. After your operation is done, the desired output is stored in an array named `$array`.